# Why does a dough with margarine absorb more oil than one with butter?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

My family makes deep-fried cakes. Normally, we use butter in the dough and fry it in canola oil. Recently though, we tried using margarine instead of butter and the cakes absorbed much more of the cooking oil than ever before.

What could be the reason for this?

First I thought that, by having a **relatively** similar, more unsaturated, molecular structure, the margarine had a greater intermolecular attraction with the canola oil than the butter with it's more saturated structure. I tried to search the web to find something to prove or disprove this, but, unfortunately, I found nothing of the sort.

Comment: I'd wonder if the margarine had water in it, and if it also had some sort of emulsifying agent.